# Can a PDF be searchable and Clearscan at the same time?

Tags: pdf, adobe, ocr, acrobat

When I use OCR in Adobe Acrobat on a PDF, I can choose either to have searchable text or Clearscan. Clearscan is pretty, but searchable text is a requirement. Why not both?

Answer (score 1):

Clearscan automatically produces files with searchable text, because it replaces images with actual fonts. A simple test will show this.

N.B.: In recent versions (>DC), Clearscan has been renamed to “Editable text and images”.